# ¿Cómo pasar un fichero a un main en java?

Tags: java, arraylist, vscode, bluej

tengo este código:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
    
public class ArrayListUse {       
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.print("You must specify an argument: filename");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        
        File fd = new File(args[0]);
        Scanner file = null;
        // Creating ArrayList object        
       
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();

        try {
            file = new Scanner(fd);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File does not exists " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
                
        // Reading file, adding lines to the list        
        while (file.hasNext()) {
            // TO COMPLETE ...
            list.add(file.nextLine());
        }
        file.close();
        
        // Sorting the list, writing it to console        
        
        Collections.sort(list);

        //Print 
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }     
}
```

El código coge un fichero pasado al main, crea una instancia de la clase `ArrayList<E>` de tipo String (list), lee el contenido del fichero linea a linea y lo vuelca en `list`, posteriormente lo ordena usando el método `sort` de la clase `java.util.Collections` y finalmente lo imprime en pantalla.

Lo que no entiendo es cómo paso el fichero al main. He leido que puedo pasar parámetros cada vez que invoco el método desde el cmd pero cada vez que lo ejecuto me dice que no existe, aún incluso habiendo compilado con el javac y no con bluej. Dejo una captura.
[image: Compilación y ejecución del programa ArrayListUse. Aunque le pase el fichero me salta el error.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias partes que me gustaría señalar por entender el propósito de tu pregunta y luego indicar posibles resultados.

```
if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.print("You must specify an argument: filename");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

En la primera condición pides del args propio del main, entra en dicha condición y "fuerzas" el programa a cerrar. ¿Porque? Se te acabara el programa ahí mismo.

Tras ello un `File fd = new File(args[0]);` otra vez referenciando del propio main. No se si se entiende el propósito del propio `String[] args` del main, es interesante buscarlo y me gustaría obviarlo para no hacer muy largo esto.

Me gusta quejarme así que aprovechemos a indicar que poner `Scanner file = null;` para dos líneas después `file = new Scanner(fd);`, ahorremos y pongamos en una sola línea. Aparte de mover la estructura del try catch.

Por finalizar usas `System.exit(0);` en el catch, pero cuando se indica `0` quiere decir que la ejecución fue bien. ¿Se quiere ese propósito o es mejor indicar que no, al no encontrar el fichero?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File fd = new File("C:\\Users\\YourUser\\Documents\\prueba.txt");
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(fd);
            // Creating ArrayList object
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); // Sin <> es un raw type

            // Reading file, adding lines to the list
            while (file.hasNext()) {
                // TO COMPLETE ...
                list.add(file.nextLine());
            }
            System.out.println(list); // Sin ordenar
            file.close();
            // Sorting the list, writing it to console
            Collections.sort(list);
            //Print
            System.out.println(list); // Ordenado, sin necesidad de llamar a .toString() porque ya recibimos tipo String
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File does not exists " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

Y de esta manera debería funcionarte al indicarla bien la ruta o si no lo haces el catch se ejecutara como debe.

Entiendo que ejecutaras por el CMD y pasas los valores por línea de comandos, pero para un fichero deberías indicarlo con otro tipo, por ello usar el `args` como si tuviera algo era erróneo.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Se me olvido, si es completamente explicito pasarlo por línea de comandos, llamas a Java NombreDelPrograma.java rutaDelFicheroQueLeera y dicho "args" o el nombre que le pongas debe tener el tipo adecuado, como un File. Que representara la ruta del fichero.